# Transaction working locally and with ngrok (https), but not working when deploying to aws amplify

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, phantom, nextjs

```
  const lamports = 0.001 * 10 ** 9;
  const fromPubKey = new PublicKey(
    'Wallet sending here'
  );
  const toPubKey = new PublicKey(
    'Wallet receiving here'
  );

  const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: publicKey,
      toPubkey: toPubKey,
      lamports,
    })
  );

  const {
    context: { slot: minContextSlot },
    value: { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight },
  } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext();

  try {
    const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection, {
      minContextSlot,
    });

    loadingToast.current = toast.loading('Transaction loading...');
    await connection.confirmTransaction({
      blockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight,
      signature,
    });

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    toast.error('Error, please try again!');
  }
```

I have this code written in a NextJS app.
Using @solana/wallet-adapter-react to connect to my phantom wallet.

Everything is working fine when testing locally, and also when passing through ngrok (to provide ssl and https)

[image: Working]

However, when I deploy my app to aws amplify (since its nextjs), when trying to send 0.001 SOL, phantom is giving me this error

[image: Not working :(]

My deployed app on aws also has SSL and HTTPS configured properly.

Comment: In the screenshot the URL under ```Approve transaction``` text is pointing to the ngrok URL. Maybe that needs to be changed and point it to some AWS URL? Also, make sure your app is launched on ```process.env.PORT``` instead of any hardcoded port number. If you are using some added environment variables then also make sure to add them in AWS env settings.

Comment: @AbdullahQureshi Yes because with the ngrok, it is working, however on the aws deployed website, it is not. Really strange

Comment: have you looked into ```process.env.PORT```. Is server up or crashed? check ```AWS``` logs. Also, check [Solana Explorer](https://explorer.solana.com)  logs.

Answer (score 1):

In the `next.config.js`
Remove the `swcMinify: true`

Worked!